# Are there any difference in the way all these arrays are declared?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim chars1 = {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars2 As Char() = {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}

Dim chars3() As Char = {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars4 As Char() = New Char(2) {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars5() As Char = New Char(2) {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
```

Do all these statements equivalent?

I got it from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable

Why vb.net allow so many ways to declare and initialize arrays? And which way is the recommended way?

Comment: When you tested for yourself, what did you find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1: Do all these statements equivalent?

To address your question let's consider the following in VB.Net:

```
Dim chars1 = {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars2 As Char() = {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars3() As Char = {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars4 As Char() = New Char(2) {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
Dim chars5() As Char = New Char(2) {"%"c, "&"c, "@"c}
```

When compiling this to IL, we get first of all the local declarations of:

```
.locals init (
    [0] char[] chArray1,
    [1] char[] chArray2,
    [2] char[] chArray3,
    [3] char[] chArray4,
    [4] char[] chArray5
)
```

Then the IL that loads these with initial values, which for `chArray1` is:

```
IL_0001: ldc.i4.3
IL_0002: newarr       [mscorlib]System.Char
IL_0007: dup
IL_0008: ldtoken      field valuetype '<PrivateImplementationDetails>'/'__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=6' '<PrivateImplementationDetails>'::'6845D198C7136E509FE40D35A01FF939DFB57BECCB075C9878949317F7D46A9C'
IL_000d: call         void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array, valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)
IL_0012: stloc.0
```

The IL to load the other array is identical with the exception of the stack location increasing by 1 each time (`stloc.1`, `stloc.2`, etc.).

So in answer to the first question - **yes the statements would appear to be equivalent**.

#### Question 2: Why vb.net allow so many ways to declare and initialize arrays?

The answer to this is somewhat less clear.

My *opinion* is that this is most likely due to the migration from VBA\VBScript\VB6 into VB.Net, and a need to preserve the "*old way*" of array declaration for people that transitioned, combined with a desire to use the "*new way*" of array declaration.

However, what is clear is that, regardless of the approach, the end result will be the same.

Comment: IL means intermediate language right? Yes. This is awesome. Most people think this is just a stupid question. I wanna know what's under the hood. Great

Comment: The end result is the same and the IL is also the same. To avoid confusion, which way of delcaration is the new one and should be recommended?

Comment: How do you get the IL language thingy?

Comment: @VibiChrisbud IL means intermediate language, indeed.  You can view IL using the built-in tool with Visual Studio, ildasm.exe.  There are also a range of free and paid tools available online to help with that.

Comment: I've had a look at the MS docs and I don't believe there is a _recommended way_, which means that it is down to individual taste or opinion.  My own preference would be to declare it like this: `Dim myVar As Char()` because I feel like this more closely matches what I would expect to see in other languages.  However, this is purely an opinion and not a recommendation